# Using @variable in mysql used as command in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've used this type of query under VB.NET 2008, but everytime I run it, it always gives me a fatal error and it's telling me to declare the @variable I've used.
Below is the sample code:

```
select js.year, js.week, js.rem_balance,
       case when js.rem_balance = 0 
                then @prev_rem_balance 
            else js.rem_balance 
       end as rem_balance_zero_or_prev,
       @prev_rem_balance := js.rem_balance
from test_jos_stock js
       inner join (SELECT @prev_rem_balance := 0) as t
order by year,week;
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring the @variable you've used?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the parameter before your select statement:

```
DECLARE @prev_rem_balance INT; --or whatever datatype it is
```

Then set it to be a specific value:

```
SET @prev_rem_balance = 1234;
```